# PowerShell - Excel - Select first worksheet in workbook

Tags: excel, powershell

I have a script that loops through a workbook and copies all tabs to a new workbook. For some reason, though, **the first tab is always being skipped**.

```
for ($i=1; $i -lt $myworkbook.Worksheets.Count; $i++) {
... other code
$SheetToCopy = $source.Worksheets.Items($i)
$sheetToCopy.Copy($target)
}
```

- I've tried setting `$i` to 0, but then powershell complains that zero is not valid.
- Tried using `$workbook.sheets.item` and `$workbook.worksheets.item`, but they seem to do the same thing

Can anyone shed some light on what is going on here?

### Additional Information:

The workbooks will never have the same named tabs, for this reason i'm using index rather than name.

Comment: Are you sure it's the first tab being skipped and not the last? From what it looks like in your code it should be `(i = 1; i <= worksheets.Count; i++)`, otherwise when it hits the last sheet with an index of say 4 and i is at 4, it's never going to copy it. Unless that's what you intended.

Comment: Ah, good eye. I'll go test that out, but i think you're right. I'm used to starting at 0, so it would work to do `<`, but in this case i need to use `<=`

Comment: Yeah, all these non-zero index based languages are for the birds! Hope that solves it.

Comment: You can add that as the answer and i'll accept it. That was the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the code you posted it looks like it may be skipping the last sheet and not the first. It should be

```
(int i = 1; i <= worksheets.Count; i++) // roughly translated from C#
```

When you have the `<` sign there (instead of `<=`) and because you're using a non-zero based index, when it hits the last sheet `i` will be equal to `worksheets.Count`, therefore skipping it since you require it to be less than `worksheets.Count`